# Are $f(t)$ and $f'(t)$ bounded and piecewise continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, piecewise-continuity

I have the function

$$
f(t) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
& -t , -2 < t \le 0\\
& t ,0 < t \le 2
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

with periodicity of $4$ such that $f(t + 4) = f(t)$.

The derivative of this function is

$$
f'(t) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
& -1 , -2 < t \le 0\\
& 1 ,0 < t \le 2
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Am I correct in saying that both $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are bounded and piecewise continuous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you are right : $f$ is bounded on $[-2, \ 2]$ and since it is a periodic function it is bounded everywhere
$f'$ is also periodic by definition and therefore bounded for the same reason. 
$f$ is everywhere continuous and $f'$ is piecewise continuous.

Comment: Great. Thank you very much for the assistance.